Group action on affine variety induces faithful action on tangent space
I have a queestion about the proof of Lemma 2.2 from the paper arxiv 1105.3739:
Let $G$ be a group acting faithfully on an irreducible affine variety $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ over $k= \Bbb C$. Assume that $x \in X$ is a fixed point and that there is a $G$-stable decomposition $m_x = V \oplus m_x^2$ of the maximal ideal $m_x$ of the stalk $O_{X,x}$.
Then the induced tangent representation $t : G \to \operatorname{GL}(T_xX)$ is faithful.

Proof. Let $g \in \operatorname{ker}  t$. Then $g$ acts trivially on $V$ , hence on all powers $V^j$ of $V$ . This
implies that the action of $g$ on $A/m^k_x$ is trivial for all $k \ge 1$. (Why?) Since $\bigcap 
m^k_x= 0$ the claim follows.

Question: Could somebody elaborate why existence of $G$-stable decomposition $m_x = V \oplus m_x^2$ of the maximal ideal $m_x$ implies that $g$ acts trivially on  $A/m^k_x$?
I hoped this can be managed somehow by easy induction of $k$, but — so assume the statement is true for $A/m^k_x$ and want to check it for $A/m^{k+1}_x$ — so we pick a $ r \in A$ and consider $t(g) \cdot r -r \in m_x^k$. How to see that the "error" $g \cdot r -r$ lives even in $m_x^{k+1}$ using the decomposition of $m_x$ from above?

This is just a gut feeling, but I think one must have the decomposition $A/m^k=V\oplus V^2 \oplus \cdots \oplus V^{k-1}$.

Suppose that $k$ is a positive integer, and we have shown that $m_x^k$ equals $V^k + m_x^{k + 1}$.  Then $m_x^{k + 1}$ equals $(V + m_x^2)(V^k + m_x^{k + 1}) = V^{k + 1} + (m_x^2 V^k + (V + m_x^2)m_x^{k + 1}) = V^{k + 1} + m_x^{k + 2}$.  So, by induction, the result holds for all positive integers $k$.  (This is GeU's gut feeling.)
Write $r - r(x) = v_1 + v_2 + \dotsb + v_k + r_{k + 1}$, where each $v_i$ belongs to $V^i$ and $r_{k + 1}$ belongs to $m_x^{k + 1}$.  Then $g r - r$ equals $g r_{k + 1} - r_{k + 1}$, hence belongs to $m_x^{k + 1}$.
